# Round decimal digits to upper value

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

I want to round decimal value digits to upper value if digit isn't zero.
I want to round the 6th digit to upper value .

```
Sample Value    = 1.0003331
Expected Value  = 1.000334
```

Comment: C? C++? PHP? Language please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want:

```
decimal scale = 1000000m;
decimal rounded = decimal.Ceiling(x * scale) / scale;
```

(The scale may be off by one :)

Obviously this will cause a problem if you try to handle very large numbers with it - they could overflow.

I'd like to *think* you could also do the same thing by adding a certain amount and then using `decimal.Round`, but it's slightly awkward without a `MidpointRounding` of `RoundTowardsZero`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
decimal.Round(Value + 0.00000049m, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero ensure that when a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest number that is away from zero.

[MSDN Decimal.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s0xa85y.aspx)